# When is a polynomial contained in the ideal generated by its partial derivatives?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $R = k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be a multivariate polynomial ring over a field $k$ of characteristic zero, and let $f\in R$.

> Is there an easy-to-test necessary and sufficient condition on $f$ such that $f$ is in the ideal of $R$ generated by its partial derivatives $\partial_if$?

Geometrically, $f\in \left(\partial_1 f,\dots, \partial_n f\right)$ is the statement that the map $f:\mathbb{A}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{A}^1$ is a submersion anywhere it is nonzero. (**Edit** per a comment of @Evangelion045: this isn't quite true. $f\in(\partial_1f,\dots,\partial_n f)$ implies that $f$ is a submersion everywhere it's nonzero, but in the opposite direction, $f$ being  a sumbersion everywhere it's nonzero only implies $f$ is in the radical of the ideal generated by its partials.)

A sufficient condition is if $f$ is homogeneous of degree $d$, due to Euler's formula

$$ d\cdot f = \sum_i x_i\partial_i f$$

I was led to the question by the surprise discovery that the statement is also true if $f$ happens to be the resolvent cubic of a monic quartic polynomial $x^4 - \sigma_1x^3 +\sigma_2x^2 - \sigma_3x +\sigma_4$, which is an inhomogeneous polynomial of degree three in the four coefficients $\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_4$ plus an auxiliary variable $\Lambda$. But the resolvent cubic is, to be sure, *weighted* homogeneous (with weight $i$ for $\sigma_i$ and weight $2$ for $\Lambda$). And sure enough, the proof for Euler's formula generalizes to this case. We have

$$ d\cdot f = \sum_i d_ix_i\partial_if$$

where $d_i$ is the weight of $x_i$ and $d$ is the weighted degree of $f$. Thus the existence of a set of weights making $f$ weighted homogeneous is also a sufficient criterion. (A google search revealed an analytic generalization in [a book of Arnol'd](https://books.google.com/books?id=nAgXhDKkdv4C&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=when%20is%20a%20polynomial%20contained%20in%20the%20ideal%20generated%20by%20its%20partial%20derivatives?&source=bl&ots=YxkhXgNvbT&sig=1ohFqYik2UjlTEKQspm9o3StX5I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj15dbw0cXLAhVr8HIKHTAaDZcQ6AEIPzAF#v=onepage&q=when%20is%20a%20polynomial%20contained%20in%20the%20ideal%20generated%20by%20its%20partial%20derivatives%3F&f=false), citing Saito.)

However, it's not quite necessary: any (nonconstant) linear function also trivially has $f\in \left(\partial_1 f,\dots,\partial_n f\right)$ since the latter is the unit ideal, while if its constant term is nonzero then it is not homogeneous with respect to any set of (positive integer) weights.

Do you know a condition that is both sufficient and necessary?

Comment: Note that this condition can be expressed using only the $k$-algebra structure of $R$: $f$ is in the ideal generated by its partial derivatives iff there exists a $k$-linear derivation $d:R\to R$ such that $d(f)=f$.  In particular, this means that the condition is preserved by any automorphisms of $R$.

Comment: How a linear function can have a non-zero constant term?

Comment: @san - not a linear form or a linear functional but a linear function. Affine function, if you prefer.

Comment: Building on Eric Wofsey's comment, I don't think one can determine a condition that is both sufficient and necessary. Every automorphic image of a weighted homogeneous polynomial will satisfy the property (this includes the affine functions), but so will the hypothetical counterexamples of the unsolved Jacobian Conjecture, if this conjecture is false.

Comment: For example, $f(x,y)=x^2y+x^2y^2+6x^4y^3+9x^6y^4$ is in the ideal generated by its partial derivatives, but its not the automorphic image of any weighted homogeneous polynomial.

Comment: @san - how did you come up with that $f$ and what's the argument it's not the automorphic image of any weighted homogeneous polynomial? (Aside: the weighted-homogeneous [or automorphic image thereof] criterion seemed way too weak in any case, because it requires the expression for $f$ as a linear combination of its partials to have a very particular form.)

Comment: The criterion is too weak, but finding counterexamples is not easy. I was playing around with some polynomials trying to find a counterexample to the Jacobian conjecture in dimension 2, and I had a (nontrivial) pair $P,Q$ with $J(P,Q)=x$. Then applying the endomorphism $x\mapsto x$ and $y\mapsto xy$ I obtained that the image of $P$, which is the $f$ in the other comment, satisfies the property.

Comment: The proof that $f$ is not a the automorphic image of a weighted homogeneous polynomial is quite long. One should take the inverse automorphism $\phi^{-1}$ and divide the proof into the two cases $deg(\phi^{-1}(x))=deg(\phi^{-1}(y))=1$, and the alternative (one of the images has degree greater than 1).

Comment: In particular, this example shows that it is easier to test directly if a polynomial is in the ideal generated by its partial derivatives than to test if it is the automorphic image of a weighed homogeneous polynomial.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith Hi. I am trying to understand why the condition on $f$ being a submersion anywhere it is nonzero, is equivalent to what you asked; but, using the Nullstellensatz, I can only arrive at $f\in\sqrt{(\partial_1 f,\ldots,\partial_n f)}.$ Do you need further assumptions on $f$? I cannot see how to conclude that it is in the ideal, not just in the square root.

Comment: Hi @Evangelion045 - I think you're right. It's true that the hypothesis about $f$ being in the ideal *implies* that the map it induces is a submersion everywhere it's nonzero, but the geometric hypothesis only implies $f$ is in the radical. There's no reason for the ideal to be radical, so that seems the best you can do. I guess I was being sloppy. I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks for answering @BenBlum-Smith.